# Specify the type of field to modify in a file

Tags: shell, shell-script, text-processing

I have a list of clients, "code", "name", "location", "etc"
and I want to make a function that asks the employee to give the client's code
and then the field he/she wants to change.
For example, "location" and then replace it with the content he or she wants.

How can I specify the type of the field that is to be changed?

Example of clients file:

```
ID,BUSINESSNAME,ADDRESS,TOWN
01,starbucks,rubin 3,memphis
```

I want to read the ID for example `01`
then ask what field I want to change
for example `address`, and the new address e.g `rubin 2`, and then
save it to the file.

The new modified file should look like this now:

```
ID,BUSINESSNAME,ADDRESS,TOWN
01,starbucks,rubin 2,memphis
```

Comment: Can you please provide a short example datafile and a demonstration of what input you would expect, and the result of the change. (You should update your Question to include this additional information.)

Answer (score 0):

A basic approach with `read` and `sed` (and no error checking):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

read -p "Enter Client ID: " client
read -p "Enter field to change: " field
read -p "Enter new data: " data

case "$field" in 
    *name) field=2 ;;
  address) field=3 ;;
     town) field=4 ;;
esac

sed -i "/^$client/ {s/[^,]*/$data/$field}" datafile
```